# Executing Jmeter testplan using Java

Tags: java, jmeter

We all know pretty well that **JMeter** is a server performance testing tool for both static and dynamic resources. I've had successfully used **JMeter** for the above written purpose through it's easy to use GUI interface. Recently we've been experiencing a lot of "*server down*" issue but we're unable to find out when exactly server is down until we're requesting something to it and get nothing in return.

So I thought of using **JMeter** as a solution here. Using **JMeter** I would be hitting the server at particular intervals, say once in every 3hours and get a response back which will correctly identify that server is working fine. Using it in GUI mode is not apt. It needs to be scheduled for every 3 hours.

Through a bit of Google's help I learnt **JMeter** could also be used in "*non GUI mode*". So I took the script and made a bat file of it. I then triggered the bat file using Java cod with the help of **Timer** class for scheduling. The script inside the bat file is :

```
jmeter -n -t E:\Jmeter.jmx -l E:\test.txt
```

Using above script I get summary report in test.txt which looks like:

```
1440049645804,576,SOAP/XML-RPC Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,583,1,1,574
```

The result was same even when the server was down. I added **"View Results Tree"** as listener in GUI and saved it but still the result was same. By default the non GUI mode gets just the summary. I would want the Response data of Result tree as well.

[image]

The Response data shown above confirms whether server is returning valid data or not. Is there any way I could add up the Response data to my result file?

Also I found the test plans could be run inside the java code using the JMeter API's and Interface i.e `JavaSamplerClient` . I searched but could not find a live example that I could understand clearly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In order to see response data you need to do the following:

   - Switch JMeter output format to XML
   - "Tell" it to save response data

   Command line solution will look like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -n -t E:\Jmeter.jmx -l E:\test.txt
   ```
2. In regards to running JMeter test from Java see chapter **4.2 Running an existing JMeter Test from Java code** of the [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui).
3. `JavaSamplerClient` - is the way of creating custom [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) Samplers, I doubt that it is what you looking for

Comment: Thanks very much you just answered what exactly I needed. Helped me a great bit. Sorry for delay in accepting the answer, I was out of city for few days.. Thanks again

Comment: @ Dmitri T is there any way by which I could run 2 test plans say `Jmeter.jmx`, `jmeter1.jmx` and save the result in two different files? Also the response data given is exorbitant and I need data only within the red marked area in the image I've provided. Is it possible to do that?